# Sorting a multiple node reference field in view based on another field of the node

Tags: views, entities

I have a view that whereby one of the fields (a node reference field) has "multiple fields settings" checked. So it has multiple values per row.

I want to sort these values based on another field of this referenced node (field_order).

I have added this to the view, but the sort does not occur. Is there any way to sort a multiple field based on a referenced field?

Comment: How did you "connect" the field_order to a value of the multiple value field?

Comment: Well that's the problem. I don't know how to connect. Both are fields of the same node.

Comment: It look like you need to use delta instead of a custom field_order field and a module for ordering like this one https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_value_widget